# Android record internal device sound

Tags: java, android, audio, record, mediarecorder

I'm still new at programming on Android device. I'm currently making an app who allows you to play drums.

I want to record the sound played by the user.

I'm using this way to record the sound :

```
recorder = new MediaRecorder();
        recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
        recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
        recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
        recorder.setOutputFile(audiofile.getAbsolutePath());
        recorder.prepare();
        recorder.start();
```

After reading the documentation and search in SO and other sites, I found nothing about my interrogation. Actually, I can record the sound and stock it in the memory, but its uses the external microphone of the device (so there is interferences and when headphones are plugged, I hear nothing).

Is there a way to record the internal sound of the device ?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

If your samples are PCM you can simple write the mixed samples to a file at the same time that you write them to the AudioTrack.

If they're compressed (aac, mp3, ...) you'll probably need to decode them in your app, and then do the same thing that I described in the first paragraph.

There's currently no way of recording from an output device, other than by the method you've tried already.